# Alternative Effect Size for Mann-Whitney-U to Cliff's Delta

Tags: r, effect-size, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, large-data

I am working with two variables that are not normally distributed with a large sample size in each group (n=287521, m=10863). After computing the U statistic and corresponding p-value, I tried to do an effect size analysis. The results of the Mann-Whitney-U test are as follows

```
Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  l_filtered and d_filtered
W = 1.081e+09, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

While my p-value is low, I want to validate this conclusion because of the large sample sizes. One approach is to calculate Cliff's Delta using the `effsize` package in R. However, I get an integer overflow error when calculating this statistic. Integers larger than 2e9 produce this error, and this statistic is calculated by producing n*m numbers either [-1, 1]. If approx 82% (2e9/(287521 x 10863) + 0.5 x (((287521 x 10863) - 2e9)/(287521 x 10863))) of those numbers are the same sign, the error occurs.

An alternative I have seen to measure effect size is to take the value of the statistic and divide by the square root of the total sample size. This produces the number 1978977, which is to be compared to a 'large effect size >0.5'. That seems to be suspiciously high to me given that limit.

My question is, what effect size analysis can I do on my data, preferably in R, that will not overflow the memory allocated to a single number?

Comment: Data don't have parameters, so "[parametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_statistics)" and "nonparametric" don't apply to data. They apply to models (and by extension, techniques based on/related to them). What are you trying to explain about your variables when you refer to them as nonparametric? Can you explain more about the original variables? (Are they 0/1?)

Comment: sorry, what I mean to say is that a parametric test will not work because they are not normally distributed. I was also unable to find a transform that made them normally distributed (as told by skew and kurtosis). As for the original variables they are in the interval [0,1], but when computing Cliff's Delta, every combination between the two samples are compared and a 1 is assigned if the first datum is greater than the second, and a -1 if it is less than, with a 0 if they are exactly equal. These numbers are all summed in the calculation of Cliff's Delta, leading to the error I described.

Comment: Parametric tests don't necessarily assume normality (again see the link in my previous comment), so the premise in your first sentence there is incorrect -- a parametric test can be based on any suitable parametric distribution.  [As an aside, note that with such a large sample you're virtually certain to reject normality even when the degree and kind of non-normality - which will always be present to some degree - is of no consequence whatever for your inference.]

Comment: However, it should be possible to compute Cliff's delta directly from the U statistic. Are your data discrete (are there ties?)  ... Any issue will actually be in computing its standard error but I expect that's doable

Comment: Thank you, that was a useful link, I understand the flaw in terminology I was making. The data are not discrete, they fall in the range between zero and one. How can you compute Cliff's delta directly from the U statistic? I have not been able to locate that information.

Comment: Dug a little more, found what you were talking about. Apparently I was confused, the statistic I was computing was the same process, but not translating into a Z score first, thus producing the error. Thank you for your guidance sir, and for anyone following this thread in the future, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Normal_approximation_and_tie_correction) is the formula to calculate Z from U. The formula for effect size is then just Z/sqrt{(n+m)}

Comment: You could post an answer (it's fine to answer your own question). Sorry for the slow response; I've been unable to spend time on this for several days.

Comment: `An alternative I have seen to measure effect size is to take the value of the statistic and divide by the square root of the total sample size`.  The `statistic` mentioned here is the *z* statistic.  This *z* statistic can be extracted from the function in base R, or can be back-calculated from the *p* value.  When this is divided by the square root of the total sample size, the result will fall approximately between -1 and 1.  This resulting statistic is usually called *r*.  I'm not a big fan of it, and I recommend Cliff's *delta*, VDA, or Glass rank biserial coefficient instead.

Answer (score 3):

The Wilcoxon two-sample test is virtually [identical to the proportional odds (PO) model without covariate adjustment](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo).  For example the Wilcoxon statistic is at its minimum if and only if the observed odds ratio (OR) from a PO model is 1.0.  With a PO model you get not only an OR but you can predicted cumulative probabilities, quantiles, and means.  [Here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/nonpar#power-and-sample-size) I show how to convert OR to things like differences in means.  In the first link you’ll find a blog article where I provide a simple formula to convert any OR to a [0-1] scaled Wilcoxon statistic (concordance probability; $c$-index; probability index).

As a side note, the Wilcoxon test assumes PO which is how it can be revived from linear rank statistic theory.  This means that the power of the Wilcoxon test is highest when the PO assumption holds, i.e., the two distributions are parallel after you take the logit transformation of the cumulative probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

After some further investigation I found two different solutions to this problem that I used for my work. The first solution was to calculate [Cohen's D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen%27s_d), which while not valid for non-normal distributions as in the problem here, is valid to use if you transform the test statistic to a value that is normally distributed. The distributions themselves don't fit the description, but the U statistic does. All that needs to be done is to calculate the corresponding Z statistic from the U statistic, the formula for which can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Normal_approximation_and_tie_correction). Then, use the formula for calculating cohen's d from Z, which can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_cohen_d_equal_to_z_statistics_How_can_I_calculate_cohen_d_using_Z_scores).

The second method I found was something I overlooked from the beginning. The f effect size for the U statistic can be calculated directly, but with such a large sample size I had to cast the variables as double in R. You can find the formula for the f effect for the U statistic [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Effect_sizes).

Comment: It's not true that Cohen's D is *invalid* for non-normal distributions. It's distribution may not be normal, & you may not be able to use standard formula to put a confidence interval on it, but that's a different issue. It's a number, you can compute it, & its meaning will be relatively straightforward to many readers. That said, what you are calling "the f effect" has a direct connection to what the MW test is testing & can also be intuitive. I would use that.

Comment: One of the two underlying assumptions in calculating Cohen's D is that [the data falls under a normal distribution](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-015-0667-z#Sec1) The other is that the variances are equal (same link).

Comment: It would be unusual to use Cohen's *d* as an effect size statistic where you've used a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney as a hypothesis test.  The original question has the correct intuition in suggesting Cliff's *delta*.  Other relevant statistics include  Vargha and Delaney’s *A*, Glass rank biserial coefficient, and probability of superiority.

Comment: If it's the software that's causing the tangle, taking a sample from a large dataset may work fine.  Or maybe try a different function in a different package.  Or, if you can get the *U* statistic from, say, the base R function, you can easily convert this to Cliff's *delta* or VDA.